# Sum of entries of Cayley table for $(\mathbb Z_n, \times)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've conjectured a general form of the sum of entries in the Cayley table for $(\mathbb Z_n, \times)$, though I'm not sure how to prove it:
$$\frac{n^2(n-1)}{2} - \frac{n}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \gcd (i,n)$$
seems to work for small values of $n$. Is this right, and how can it be proven?

Comment: To clarify: (1) Does $\mathbb Z_n$ mean the ring of integers modulo $n$, also written $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$? (2) Are you summing all $n^2$ entries, or just the $\phi(n)^2$ entries for invertible elements? (3) Are you choosing integer representatives for elements of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ among $[0,n-1]$ or $[1,n]$ or some other set of primitives?

Comment: (1) Yes, $\mathbb Z_n = \mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z,$ (2) summing over all $n^2$, and (3) integer representatives are in $[0,n-1].$ Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Any thoughts, anyone?

Comment: This question trivializes one of the questions in a proof-based math competition - in fact, it's almost exactly the solution. Even if it's not meant to mess with the competition, it might still be a problem...

Comment: Uh oh, hopefully contestants have not seen this. Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is true.

We can compare the multiplication table with another "imaginary" table, where every row contains an copy of $0,1,\cdots, n-1$ each.

The sum of the entry of the table we constructed is simply $n(0+1+\cdots+(n-1)) = \frac{n^2(n-1)}{2}$, which is your first term. Hence, we just need to show that the difference between the multiplication table and our imaginary table is $$\frac n2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\gcd(i,n).$$

We can consider three cases:

**The row $\times 0$:** since all entries in the multiplication table are $0$, the difference to our imaginary table is $$0+1+\cdots+(n-1) = \frac n2(n-1).$$

**The row $\times k$, with $\gcd(k,n) = 1$:** You can see that it is just an rearrangement of $0, 1, \cdot, n-1$. For instance, if $n=15, k=7$, the row becomes $$0,7,14,6,13,5,12,4,11,3,10,2,9,1,8.$$

So the multiplication table and the imaginary table are essentially the same, i.e, the difference is $$0 = \frac n2(1-1)$$.

**The row $\times k$, with $\gcd(k,n) = d > 1$:** We know that the modular equation $kx \equiv t \pmod n$ has no solution when $d \not | \ t$ and $d$ solutions when $d | t$. For instance, if $n=15, k=6$, then $d = 3$ and the row becomes $$\color{red}{0,6,12,3,9},0,6,12,3,9,0,6,12,3,9.$$

In this case, the difference between the multiplication table and the imaginary table will be $$\frac nd(0+1+\cdots + (d-1)) = \frac nd\frac{d(d-1)}{2} = \frac n2(d-1).$$

All the nonzero rows (there are $n-1$ of them) corresponds to either the second or third case, so after compensating the first case to the lase two cases you get

$$
\frac n2(n-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac n2(\gcd(i,n)-1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac n2\gcd(i,n).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Some minor comments. The sequence you are after is
$$
a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}n\ \{ij/n\}
$$
where $\{\,\cdot\,\}$ denotes the fractional part.

This is known to be given by the expression in the OP, cf. [A160255](http://oeis.org/A160255),
$$
a_n\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2} n (n-\gcd (i,n))=0, 1, 6, 16, 40, 63, 126,\dots
$$

More generally, one expects a similar result for
$$
a_n(f)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f(n\ \{ij/n\})
$$
where $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ is an arbitrary function. I find
$$
a_n(f)\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(i)T_{i,n}
$$
where $T_{i,n}$ "is the number of occurrences of the digit $n-1$ as least significant digit in the base-$i$ multiplication table", cf. [A095026](https://oeis.org/A095026).